# Cookies are not set in an AJAX/PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, cookies

I'm developing a login form using an ajax calling.

First of all, I have my HTML code that comes below this paragraph

```
<form id="login_form" name="login" method="POST">                   
   <input id="login_email" name="login_email" type="text" placeholder="Email" />
   <input id="login_password" name="login_password" type="password" placeholder="password" />
   <input id="login_checkbox" name="login_remember" type="checkbox" />
   <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

After verifying with JQuery all the errors in the client, I do an ajax calling like the code below.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '../ajax/login.php',
    cache: false,
    type: "POST",
    data: $( "#login_form" ).serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        if (!data){ //Logged correctly!
            window.location = "../page/colabora";
    }
});
```

Then, login.php has been called... and here is the problem. I try to set a cookie like `setcookie('usr', $value)` with the id of the client logged but there's no cookie comming back.

Checking colabora.php, it doesn't bring any cookie as a callback response.

Where could be the problem?

Thanks in advice

---

## UPDATE

I should have been more specific with the ajax calling.... My script takes the form comming bellow.

```
// Our custom secure way of starting a PHP session.
$secure = false;
// This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id.
$httponly = true;
// Forces sessions to only use cookies.
if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === FALSE) {
    header("Location: ../page/serror?err=-2");
    exit();
}
// Gets current cookies params.
$cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
session_set_cookie_params($cookieParams["lifetime"], $cookieParams["path"], $cookieParams["domain"], $secure, $httponly);
// Sets the session name to the one set above.
session_name('sec_session_id');
session_start();            // Start the PHP session 
session_regenerate_id();    // regenerated the session, delete the old one. 

setcookie('usr', 'example_cookie');
```

---

## UPDATE 2

After a lot of time and many time wasted trying to find a solution, I just decided to record an aux session param in the login.php and record the cookie in colabora.php when the user has been successfully conected.

Comment: `session_start()` for sure!

Comment: problem is at server side. ajax/login.php is your problem

Comment: Do you have some extra output before SETCOOKIE? Something in the error_log? Check if you have something like "headers already sent..."

Comment: I've updated my answer being more specific with my php code. I got a secure session session_start. I agree with Panoptic, but I don't find the issue. I've tried to debug everything but apparently, there's any problem. About outputs, I echo json_encode($error_msg); a variable error when there are errors and $success if everything's okay.

Answer (score 1):

try to add:

```
session_write_close()
```

from the PHP site:

It is a good idea to call `session_write_close()` before proceeding to a redirection using

```
header("Location: URL");
exit();
```

because it ensures the session is updated (in a file or into a database, depending on the handler you're using) BEFORE you redirect the visitor somewhere else.

Comment: I just set the `session_write_close` between `session_regenerate_id();` and `setcookie('usr', 'example_cookie');` but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

start the session using session_start() in your php code. Then it will surely set the cookie